# Jade-like templating language for python and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, pug, slim-lang, pyjade

Is there a templating language like [jade](http://jade-lang.com/) that is for both python and javascript and has the same syntax on each?

Pyjade does not have the same syntax for the engine-specific parts as jade, and therefore will not work for me.

I am willing to use something like [jinja2js](https://github.com/mkerrin/pwt.jinja2js), but jinja2js doesn't work for pyjade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm Syrus, author of **pyjade**. I have developed recently the package [jsjinja](https://github.com/SyrusAkbary/jsjinja)
which converts Jinja2 templates to javascript in a new and different way.

Check it out! ;)